# Android Emulator doesn't support avx2?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulator

I'm running the latest Android Emulator on my Windows host. The `avx2` cpu flags is missing when I check the `cpuinfo` by `cat /proc/cpuinfo` inside the Android guest.

[image]

I've upgraded the Android Emulator to latest(31.1.4 by far) in `Android Studio`.

I'm pretty sure that my host PC has `avx2` supported, as I checked by `Coreinfo.exe`. I suspect this is a known issue to google, as I don't see this problem on my Mac host using the same version of Android Emulator.

Comment: According to https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/sku/88193/intel-core-i56200u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-2-80-ghz/specifications.html your CPU should support AVX2, could it be that the emulator is using an old kernel or a kernel that does not have AVX compiled in or specifically disabled? https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTY0OTM looks like AVX was added in the 3.15 kernel.

Comment: Alternatively some motherboards might have AVX disabled in the BIOS settings so there would be another place to check https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-ISA-Extensions/BIOS-and-AVX-AVX2-AVX512/m-p/1127323

Comment: Thanks @Mokubai for the info, This should not due to the BIOS setting, as I can see AVX2 supported in Coreinfo.exe ran on my Host PC. Also, I'm running Android guest which API level 11, so the kernel version is up 4.4+.

Answer (score 0):

Run the emulator with the `-qemu -cpu max` options.

That might enable avx2 if your host supports it.